# how to resolve org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException

Tags: spring, hsqldb

hi i am using spring config.xml to config my embedded database hsqldb. my spring config is as below:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql" />

</jdbc:embedded-database>
<bean id="adapterDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="datasource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/db/lmexadapter_db" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

when run run my appication which is using above spring config.xml it give me a exception as below:

org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'datasource' of bean class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: Bean property 'datasource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

please help to resolve this as soon as possible

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource doesn't have a "setDatasource" method. It does have a protected field "datasource", however, which you could expose by subclassing and providing a setter.

Comment: i have solve the above problem by using depends-on attribute of bean and now i am getting a problem of user not found "SA" how i can resolve this